# How to remove form from page after submitting?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I want the form field to be removed from the page after the user clicks on the submit button, however I can see that the form field is briefly removed and then immediately restored. I don't know why this is happening, if anyone could explain it to me I would be most appreciative.

```
$("form").on("submit",function () {
    $("form").remove();
});
```

Comment: Please post a complete code example. Is the form simply posting back to the page and reloading it? You haven't provided enough information.

Comment: The form will be submitted and page will be refreshed. Use `return false ` or `event.prevenrDefault` and submit the form by ajax

Comment: And then just change the `visible` attribute.

Comment: If you submit it to the same page, you're just reloading the page thus the form will be visible again. You can use the `event.preventDefualt()` to not submit the form and remove it. Example http://jsfiddle.net/fducqxqx/. Please post up the complete code like @j08691 said.

Comment: You can hide that form, from getting displayed to the user, by changing it's display property from :

$("form").css('display','block');
to 
$("form").css('display','none');

Comment: event.preventDefault() did the trick. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just so it can be marked as answered.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fducqxqx/

HTML

```
<form action="#" method="POST" class="form">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Some Data Input" />
    <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

jQuery

```
$("form").on("submit",function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //To not refresh the page
    $("form").remove(); //Remove the form
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your form is *"restored"* even if you use `$("form").remove();` cause...
**your page is being refreshed**.
To  avoid that you should submit your form to a form processing server script using AJAX and preventing the default form `event` to trigger:

```
$("form").on("submit", function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var data = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
        url: "mail.php",
        type: "post",
        data: data,
        success : function( response ){
            // hide form or do something with response
        }
    });
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/
http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/